# Zsh do utilities distinction

Tags: zsh, system-information

How do Zsh distinguish utility/file if it's executable either binary or script, or just file, or shell builtin, etc, etc ?

Comment: Do you want to know if the Zsh shell does this in some special way compared to _other_ shells? AFAIK, all shells work pretty much the same way unless they support auto loadable modules etc. Is your question relating to the _internals_ of the shell, or should the answer concentrate on the way commands, in general, are executed from the command line, regardless of the shell?

Answer (score 4):

When a word appears in a command position, the first thing that zsh checks is if it's an [alias](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Aliasing) or a [reserved word](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Reserved-Words). This happens early on, as part of grammatical parsing. Zsh knows about reserved words and aliases because it has an internal table for each. In addition, words ending with certain suffixes are expanded in a way that's similar to normal aliases, if the suffix is of the form `.ext` where there is an active suffix alias defined with `alias -s ext=…`. Reserved words are fixed in the source code of zsh (except that they can be disabled). Aliases can be defined at runtime.

When zsh is ready to [execute a command](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#Command-Execution), for a word in command position:

- If the word appears in the internal table of [functions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Functions), it's executed as a function. Functions can be defined at runtime.
- Otherwise, if the word appears in the internal table of [builtins](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands). There is an initial set of builtins in the source code of zsh, but additional builtins can be defined by [dynamically loaded modules](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Zsh-Modules).
- Otherwise, if the [`auto_cd` option](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fCD) is set and the word is the path to a directory and the command has no arguments, zsh behaves as if the command was `cd` with this word as argument.
- Otherwise, zsh treats the word as the name of an external command. It performs a [`PATH` lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) like the system function [`execvp`](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=execvp&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+13.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html), although like most shells zsh calls `execve` directly.
- If the attempt to execute an external command fails but a matching file exists, zsh may try to execute the command indirectly, depending on the content of the file:

  - If the file starts with `#!`, zsh reads the interpreter path on that line and attempts to invoke the interpreter. This is the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) mechanism. On modern systems the kernel takes care of this so zsh's implementation is only necessary on some ancient systems.
  - Otherwise, if the file looks like a text file, zsh invokes `/bin/sh` on it. This behavior is for a backward compatibility for before the shebang mechanism existed and people used to just drop shell scripts in the command search path and they would be executed by `sh`.
- If none of this managed to execute a command, zsh runs the function [`command_not_found_handler`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#index-command_005fnot_005ffound_005fhandler), if it exists. This function is typically used to print a message like “Command 'foo' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install somepackage”, but it could also try to execute the command in some different way.

Comment: *"This behavior is for a backward compatibility for before the shebang mechanism existed"* Not only. That's a POSIX requirement. POSIX doesn't specify the shebang mechanism. The POSIX way to write a POSIX sh script is to leave off the she-bang.